# python: How to create a dictionary from two files

Tags: dictionary

```
import os
d = {}
with open("time.txt") as f:
for line in f:
    (key, val) = line.split()
    d[int(key)] = val

print (d)
```

> I have **days.txt** and **time.txt** so how to create dictionary from the two file.

### **days.txt**

Mo Tu We Th Fr

### **time.txt**

19:00 18:00 16:00 20:00 23:00

### **My expected output is**

```
"Mo": 19:00
"Tu": 18:00
"We": 16:00
"Th": 20:00
"Fr": 23:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code and put the comments so you can understand:

```
import os
d = {}

#opening and reading the words from days.txt
days = open("days.txt", 'r').read().split(" ")

#added reading mode to the open function
with open("time.txt", "r") as f:
    #Gives an array that reads each word separated by space
    f = f.read().split(' ')

    #parsing the list by ids is better in my opinion
    for i in range(len(f)):
        #adding the i element of days to the dict and element i of f as the value
        d[days[i]] = f[i]

print(d)
```

Comment: Hi Anes, from the above code I'm getting output is like **{'Mo': '19:00', 'Tu': '18:00', 'We': '16:00', 'Th': '19:00', 'Fr\n': '19:00\n'}** and it is fine but last value is **'Fr\n': '19:00\n'**. Any idea?

Comment: @hariraj, use `f.read().rstrip().split()`

Comment: Hi Mr Olvin when my time.txt file contains only one value i'm expecting output should be 'Mo': '19:00', 'Tu': '19:00', 'We': '19:00', 'Th': '19:00', 'Fr': '19:00' but I'm getting only 'Mo': '19:00' .Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

See below. Read the 2 files - zip the data and generate a dict

```
with open('time.txt') as f1:
  t = f1.readline().split()
with open('days.txt') as f2:
  d = f2.readline().split()
data = dict(p for p in zip(d,t))
print(data)
```

output

```
{'Mo': '19:00', 'Tu': '18:00', 'We': '16:00', 'Th': '20:00', 'Fr': '23:00'}
```

Comment: `dict(zip(d, t))` will work

Comment: Is there a way to create a file based on a **key** in dictionary and dump the key based value to the file?

Comment: @hariraj Yes - there is. Give it a try. Please accept the answer.

Comment: Hi Mr balderman and Olvin when my time.txt file contains only one value i'm expecting output should be **'Mo': '19:00', 'Tu': '19:00', 'We': '19:00', 'Th': '19:00', 'Fr': '19:00'** but I'm getting only **'Mo': '19:00'** .